# Set cron for Reindex (specific) indexes

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, cron, index

I want to set an cronjob for reindexing some indexes, but preferably not all.

- First of all, how would I set one up for all?
- And if possible how to I exclude a specific index?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To reindex all indexes:
`php -f indexer.php reindexall`

To retrieve a full list of available indexes:
`php -f indexer.php info`

Then specify the type of index you would like to reindex like so:
`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute`

Below is the full list of individual commands:
`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price`
`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url`
`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat`
`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat`
`php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product`
`php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`
`php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock`
`php indexer.php --reindex tag_summary`

To retrieve a full list of indexer commands:
`php -f indexer.php help`

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this thread for the reindexing issue,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827996/magento-reindexing-price-programmatically

You can set the file you create for cron. Set cron with defined interval from the cpanel.

Answer (score 2):

You can set below code in one .sh file for specific index and set this sh file in to your cron tab

```
echo "catalog_product_attribute"
date
php /YOurMagentoDir/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For all indexs:

```
$processes = $indexer->getProcessesCollection();
foreach ($processes as $process) {
    $process->reindexEverything(); 
}
```

You can ask if it need to be reindexed by :

```
if ($process->getStatus == Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX)
```

For some indexs:

```
    $index_codes = array('catalog_product_attribute', 'catalog_product_price', 'cataloginventory_stock');
    foreach($index_codes as $code){
       $process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode($code);
       $process -> reindexEverything();
    }
```

Good Luck!